# Using validate_presence_of with strict validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, shoulda

I’m using the [Shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) gem. I’m using the `validate_presence_of` method. It is working nicely. It doesn’t seem to work, however, when using a strict validation. Example:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :status, presence: true # works
 validates :status, presence: true, strict: true # does not work
end

describe Thing do
  let(:thing) { FactoryGirl.build_stubbed :thing }
  subject { thing }
  it { should validate_presence_of :status }
end
```

Any idea how I can make it work? Maybe strict validations just aren’t supported? I can’t seem to find information about this in the repository or in the docs.

Comment: I think it's simply not supported. I've never seen the `strict` option used in a real Rails app.

Comment: @AndyWaite This is probably why Rails gets laughed at so much. We should be more rigorous about enforcing data integrity.

Comment: I'd say it's more common to enforce this kind of thing as a non-null database constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `strict` validators are tested like this:

```
describe Thing do
  subject(:thing) { FactoryGirl.build_stubbed :thing }

  it { should validate_presence_of(:status).strict }
end
```